# django feedparser limit the result

Tags: django, tags, feedparser, inclusion

im doing something with feedparser: i have a templatetag for display "news" in my home page, but , how ill limit the feedparser result?

## inclusion tag

```
from django.template import Template, Library
import feedparser
register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('rss_render.html')
def rss_render(object): #RSS URL "object"
    rss = feedparser.parse(object)       
    return {'rss': rss}
```

## template

```
<ul>
{% for r in rss.entries %}
<li> <a href="{{ r.link }}" target="_blank" title="{{ r.title }}">{{ r.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I do apologise, not strictly a keyword, but I still find using object as a variable name not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Take [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/311/) Django snippet for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's `slice` template tag:

```
{% for r in rss.entries|slice:":10" %}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice